# Is there any way of knowing total transactions count (pagination)?

Tags: transactions, horizon

In the transactions endpoint e.g.:

https://horizon-testnet.stellar.org/accounts/GAZHWW2NBPDVJ6PEEOZ2X43QV5JUDYS3XN4OWOTBR6WUACTUML2CCJLI/transactions?cursor=&limit=20&order=desc

Is there any way of knowing the **total** transactions count from the response?
Is there any way of knowing the total pages so I can display that in the UI?

And for that matter, how do I know there is a next page. The `next` link is always present even if there are no records in the next page.

I'm not sure I understand how the pagination works here.

Thanks.

---

EDIT:
From the answer I got from @Johan Stén (in his comment):

> When the link to your *current* page is the same as the link to the *next*
>   page, you're at the end. I can't explain why it's like that, I'm just
>   telling you how it is

And digging some more:
The concept is somehow still unclear.

In the link I provided there are 39 transaction total (using `limit` 20 => 2 pages).   but if I follow the `next` until `current` (`self`) == `next`, I'm at the **3rd** page where there are no records at all.

So at page 2 I can't tell if there are no more pages...

Is this how it suppose to work? :/ should I read ahead the `next` block just to see if there are no more records in the next page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding knowing when it ends, IIRC the *next* `next`-link will be the identical to the one pointing to it when you've reached the end.

I don't think there's an easy way of finding the number of transactions of an account, except for enumerating them and counting.

Comment: Can you please elaborate? what do you mean by `"the next next-link will be the identical to the one pointing to it"`? there are the `_links.next` and for each record there is `paging_token`. what is the logic there?

Comment: When the link to your *current* page is the same as the link to the *next* page, you're at the end. I can't explain *why* it's like that, I'm just telling you how it *is*.

Comment: I see what you mean. however this is somehow "tricky": in the link I provided there are 39 transaction total (2 pages). but if I follow the `next` until `current` (`self`) == `next`, I'm at the 3rd page where there are no records at all. is this how it suppose to work? :/ should I read ahead the next block just to see if there are no more records in the next page?

Comment: Yes, you should.

Comment: That really seems a bad design IMHO

Comment: Well, I can't really help you with *that* :)